# Create ZIP Files and Deploy as GitHub-Release on AppVeyor

Tags: appveyor, electron-packager

I wan't to create ZIP Files on `AppVeyor` to publish it on `GitHub` as an `Release`.

Currently, the Build-Process make following Steps:

- Install Node.js `v7`
- Start the `.\Build-All.bat`

The **Bild.bat** has following Steps:

- Create `Temp` and `Build` Directory
- Move `Source` to `Temp`
- Install depencies with `npm install`
- Start `electron-packager` to create binary files (See directory structure of `/Build/` directory)

**Directory Structure:**

```
/Source/
/Build/
  L /DSTEd-darwin-x64/
  L /DSTEd-linux-armv7l/
  L /DSTEd-linux-ia32/
  L /DSTEd-linux-x64/
  L /DSTEd-mas-x64/
  L /DSTEd-win32-ia32/
  L /DSTEd-win32-x64/
/Temp/
/Build.bat
```

Here is that, what i want:

> Package each Build-Directory (for sample `/Build/DSTEd-win32-x64/`) to an ZIP-Archive like `/Build/DSTEd-win32-x64.zip`
>
> Add all ZIP-Archives (`/Build/DSTEd-*-*.zip`) to the release

I had created manually a Release on `GitHub` for sample; That is, what i want:
 https://github.com/DST-Tools/DSTEd/releases/tag/1.0.0

Here is my **appveyor.yml**:

```
version: 1.0.0-{build}

# Set the Node Version
environment:
  matrix:
    - nodejs_version: "7"

# Install scripts. (runs after repo cloning)
install:
  - ps: Install-Product node $env:nodejs_version 
  - npm -g install electron-packager
  - .\Build-All.bat

# Caching
cache:
  - node_modules 

# Deployment Options
deploy:
  tag: $(appveyor_build_version)
  release: 'DSTEd v${appveyor_build_version} - Pre-Release (Preview)'
  description: ' ![Preview](https://github.com/DST-Tools/DSTEd/raw/master/Screenshots/preview.png)  ## Pre-Release v1.0.0 (Preview) Builded binarys for `Windows` (`32bit` & `64bit`), `Linux` (`32bit`, `64bit` & `armv7`) and `Mac OS X` (`darwin` & `mas`, only `64bit`).'
  provider: GitHub
  auth_token:
    secure: b202f536350628ff69af69d08daee9f76a9cff20
  artifact: '**\*.zip'
  draft: false
  prerelease: true
  on:
    branch: master
    appveyor_repo_tag: true

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

build: OFF
test: OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Missed part is [artifact packaging](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/). You can list all those folders are artifacts and Appveyor will zip them for you. After that deployment will "see" them.

Side note: you might want to remove `on/branch:master` part because in most cases tag name replaces branch name in incoming webhook. More details are [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/#deploy-on-tag-github-and-gitlab-only). In general I would recommend to start with simplest possible deployment configuration and add settings one by one after basic one works.

Comment: is there any possibility to build artifacts only on deploy tags? In my case I need to build an installer only on deploy tags, not in build or test.

Answer (score 0):

The [packaging artifacts](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/) is very complex. By the docs, you can define filters there won't work correctly.

I've implement a own solution to trigger the `before_deploy`. Before the deployment-phase starts, a Script package the Files as ZIP and add these as an Artifact:

```
# Deployment Options
before_deploy:
  - node .\Tools\PackageBuild.js
  - ps: Get-ChildItem .\Build\*.zip | % { Push-AppveyorArtifact $_.FullName -FileName $_.Name }
```

On the Deployment-Process we add all available artifacts to leave the property blank:

```
deploy:
  [...]
  artifact: #leave blank
```